# How to control feature subsetting in random forest in scikit-learn?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to change the way that random forest algorithm using in subsetting features for every node. The original algorithm as it is implemented in Scikit-learn way is randomly subsetting. I want to define which subset for every new node from several choices of several subsets. Is there direct way in scikit-learn to control such method? If not, is there any way to update the same code of Scikit-learn? If yes, which function in the source code is what you think should be updated?

Answer (score 1):

Short version: This is all you.

I assume by "subsetting features for every node" you are referring to the random selection of a subset of samples and possibly features used to train individual trees in the forest. If that's what you mean, then you aren't building a random forest; you want to make a nonrandom forest of particular trees.

One way to do that is to build each `DecisionTreeClassifier` individually using your carefully specified subset of features, then use the `VotingClassifier` to combine the trees into a forest. (That feature is only available in 0.17/dev, so you may have to build your own, but it is super simple to build a voting classifier estimator class.)

Comment: Dear Andreus, many thanks for your appreciated time and your answer. Maybe my question was not very clear. Let me please explain it. The control that I want is on the level of node, not in the level of tree. What you suggest is on the level of tree. What I want is exactly the same thing that happen in Random Forest where the subsetting of features is performed in the level of every node of every tree in the forest. The difference as you mentioned: the original RF randomly subsets, what I ask for not randomly subsets. However, still both solution use random re-sampled data. Thank you.

Comment: sklearn has two different random forests. RandomForestClassifier does NOT use random splits; it decides splits on the basis of maximum information gain using the `criterion` algorithm, just like each DecisionTree does. The ExtraTreesClassifier DOES use some randomness in the splits.

If you are wanting to manually control what happens at each node, that is, again, all you.

Comment: Dear Andreus, many thanks again for your appreciated time. I completely agree with you about the Splitting point. What I am talking about is the subsetting of features. Random forest at each node, (1) chooses randomly subset of features (my question concern) and then (2) splits based on the gini impurity or the information gain (your comment point). However, both of the two actions are in the level of nodes. So as you said I have to do from scratch. Do you mean build new class for a decision tree Or there is possible way you suggest where I can edit the Scikit-learn code? Thank you.